# Validating an employee ID without using a regular expression- Python

Tags: python, validation

I'm trying to figure out this ask: I'm trying to validate an employee id with the following conditions:

It must consist of 6-10 characters followed by 2 numeric digits.
It must be done WITHOUT using a regular expression. 
My professor says it's possible but I'm having a hard time:

```
my_string = 'Abc1223423'


if len(my_string) <= 5 and len(my_string) > 13:
    print('Please enter a password with length between 6 and 12')
if my_string != my_string[:2].isdigit():
    print("Renter your password with two ending digits")
if my_string != my_string[0:10].isalpha():
    print("Please enter a password between 6 and 10 letters followed by 2 digits")
```

This is what I have so far. I'm allowed to use lists, variables, isdigit and isalpha. Basically everything except using regex or any other libraries.

Anyone have any idea how to approach this? I don't get why my .isdigit condition is not working but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: right now, with `my_string[:2]` you are checking the first two characters in the string and not the last two characters. to check the last two characters, use this: `my_string[-2:]`. To filter every other character other than the last two characters use this `my_string[:-2]`

Comment: `my_string[:2].isdigit()` is either `True` or `False`, so there's no way it can be equal to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to *correct* your code. This should do the job:

```
my_string = 'Abc1223423'
if len(my_string) <= 7 and len(my_string) >= 13:
    print('Please enter a password with length between 8 and 12')
elif not my_string[-2:].isdigit():
    print("Renter your password with two ending digits")
elif not my_string[:-2].isalpha():
    print("Please enter a password between 6 and 10 letters followed by 2 digits")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(my_string) in range(8, 13) and my_string[:-2].isalpha() and my_string[-2:].isdigit():
  print('valid')
else:
  print('invalid')
```

...should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! You all helped out tremendously. I ended up going with this:

```
my_string = 'AbcdEf00'

def validate(employee_ID):
    if len(employee_ID) not in range(6,13):
        return print("Please enter a password greater than 6 and less than 12")
    if not employee_ID[-2:].isdigit():
        return print("Please enter 2 digits at the end of the pw.")
    if not employee_ID[:-2].isalpha():
        return print("Please enter 6-10 alphabetic characters in the begining")
    else:
        return print("Valid Password")


validate(my_string)
```

Feel free to use this if you all ever need it or if anyone else does.